# Dynamically updating ListView with extended SimpleCursorAdapter and Alternate LiteItem Styles

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, android-adapter

hi im displaying a ListView with `SimpleCursorAdapter` and alternat `ListItem` styles, i want to dynamically update the list if the user is on the view and an update occurs. In my ListActivity i have done

```
 adapter.swapCursor(newCursor);
 //notify
```

in my adapter which extends from `SimpleCursorAdapter` i have two overridden methods

```
 @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {         
            return 2;
        }
```

and

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
             adapCursor.moveToPosition(position);//adapCursor is being set in the constructor
        int i= adapCursor.getInt(adapterCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("isactive"));

         return i==1?i:0;

      }
```

now the problem is when i update the adapter in the activity the updated cursor is not available in `getItemViewType` method and hence an index out of bound exception is thrown...

How can i get the updated cursor in it or return proper `ItemViewType`

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getCursor()` method to get the right reference to the `Cursor` on which the adapter is based, even after changing it with `swapCursor()`. This way you don't need to manually keep/update the reference to the `Cursor`.

Answer (score 1):

found the solution

just overrided the `swapCursor` method

```
        @Override
        public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor c){         
            super.swapCursor(c);
            adapCursor=c;
            return c;               
        }
```

Comment: Or you could just use `getCursor()` instead of your reference.

Comment: @Luksprog much cleaner that way i dont have to call `super.swapCursor` put it in the answer and i shall accept it...tnx for the info